# Docker public registry push fails: Repository does not exist

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm trying to push my docker image up into the public docker registry:

```
$ docker login
Username (binarybana): 
WARNING: login credentials saved in /home/jknight/.dockercfg.
Login Succeeded

$ docker images
REPOSITORY              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
binarybana/dev-fedora   latest              10c7881fbaca        24 hours ago        1.148 GB
binarybana/fedoradev    latest              10c7881fbaca        24 hours ago        1.148 GB
binarybana/fedora-dev   latest              10c7881fbaca        24 hours ago        1.148 GB
<none>                  <none>              b44397dc4c99        24 hours ago        1.148 GB
<none>                  <none>              a98c27ba4738        24 hours ago        1.141 GB
<none>                  <none>              775c74a34add        24 hours ago        1.141 GB
<none>                  <none>              2be2491d2354        24 hours ago        1.141 GB
docker.io/fedora        21                  93be8052dfb8        7 days ago          241.3 MB

$ docker push binarybana/dev-fedora

Do you really want to push to public registry? [Y/n]: Y
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/binarybana/dev-fedora] (len: 0)
FATA[0001] Repository does not exist: docker.io/binarybana/dev-fedora 

$ docker push binarybana/fedora-dev

Do you really want to push to public registry? [Y/n]: Y
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/binarybana/fedora-dev] (len: 0)
FATA[0002] Repository does not exist: docker.io/binarybana/fedora-dev
```

Yet, I've already created the repository (viewable [here](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/binarybana/fedora-dev/)). And I've also tried to push to repository names that I haven't already created (the first try in the example above).

I think the (len: 0) has something to do with it, but I can't google it. Also I originally created the image from a dockerfile as:

```
docker build -t binarybana/fedora-dev .
```

Thanks.

Comment: does it work if you give registry..../binarybana/dev-fedora

Comment: Ahh yes, that was a typo, but trying dev-fedora gives the same result (edited the question accordingly). Good eye though!

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Always build your image with "username" and "tag"

`docker build -t <username>/dev-fedora:latest .`

After building push the image

`docker push <username>/dev-fedora:latest`

Comment: this was the answer for me

Answer (score 25):

if you are using docker.io ( dockerhub repo ),  you need to tag it including the name docker.io in it.

```
docker tag ${image_id} docker.io/${login_name}/${image_name}
```

and then

```
docker push docker.io/${login_name}/${image_name}
```

is OK.

Comment: Oh my gosh, so simple and yet so much painful searching before finding your answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I also encountered this error `Repository does not exist: gcr.io/my-project-id/my-container` when attempting to push an image to [Google Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/).

My confusion came from a misunderstanding of Docker's definition of "repository".

> A repository is a set of Docker images. A repository can be shared by pushing it to a registry server. The different images in the repository can be labeled using tags.

When Docker says that a repository does not exist, it means that there is no image that it can find locally that is [tagged](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) with that `registry.host/user-name/image-name` combination.

*Note: The [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) registry is the [default](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockerimages/), so that part can be omitted if you are pushing there.*

**Steps to fix this issue:**

1. Double check what images you have available locally.

   ```
   $ docker images
   REPOSITORY              TAG     IMAGE ID      CREATED     VIRTUAL SIZE
   gcr.io/my-proj/my-typo  v1      40c2ae2dedb8  2 days ago  427.8 MB
   ```
2. If there is a typo, you can run the `docker tag` command to fix it.

   ```
   $ docker tag gcr.io/my-proj/my-typo:v1 gcr.io/my-proj/my-cntr:v1
   ```
3. Now, you should be able to push the image using the complete name, including the tag.

   ```
   $ docker push gcr.io/my-proj/my-cntr:v1
   ```

   *Note: Use `gcloud docker -- push` instead of `docker push` if you are pushing to the Google Container Registry.*

Comment: Thanks for your explanation about the definition of a repository, very useful to understand the actual issue I had.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Amazon AWS, before you can push your Docker images to Amazon ECR, you need to create a repository to store them in. You can create Amazon ECR repositories with the AWS Management Console, or with the AWS CLI and AWS SDKs.

**To create a repository**

1.) Open the Amazon ECS console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/.

2.) From the navigation bar, choose the region to create your repository in.

3.) On the Repositories page, choose Create repository.

4.) For Repository name, enter a unique name for your repository and choose Next step.

5.) Now you should be able to push to your AWS repo!

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the complete image name. When you don't specify the tag while building, it's `latest`, so you should say

```
docker push binarybana/fedora-dev:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Santosh Gandhe's answer, if you want to push to specific repository rather than under your login name

`docker tag ${image_name} docker.io/${login_name}/${remote_repo_name}:${image_name}`
and then
`docker push docker.io/${login_name}/${remote_repo_name}:${image_name}`

Also, don't forget to do `docker login` first.